# Haskell Either Applicative where the Left is a Monoid

Tags: haskell

I'm currently learning Haskell and are starting to understand applicatives.

I wanted an Either Applicative where the left side is a monoid, so I created this as a learning exercise:

```
module EitherLeftMonoid where

data Error = InvalidName | UnderAge deriving (Eq, Show)

data Person = Person { name :: String, age :: Int } deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

data EitherLeftMonoid a b = Lefty a
                          | Righty b
                          deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Monoid a => Functor (EitherLeftMonoid a) where
  fmap _ (Lefty a)  = Lefty a
  fmap f (Righty b) = Righty (f b)

instance Monoid a => Applicative (EitherLeftMonoid a) where
  pure                  = Righty
  Lefty a <*> Lefty a'  = Lefty (a `mappend` a')
  Lefty a <*> _         = Lefty a
  _ <*> (Lefty a)       = Lefty a
  Righty f <*> Righty x = Righty (f x)

mkName :: String -> EitherLeftMonoid [Error] String
mkName "" = Lefty [InvalidName]
mkName s  = Righty s

mkAge :: Int -> EitherLeftMonoid [Error] Int
mkAge n | n < 13    = Lefty [UnderAge]
        | otherwise = Righty n

mkPerson :: String -> Int -> EitherLeftMonoid [Error] Person
mkPerson n a = Person <$> mkName n <*> mkAge a
```

Output:

```
Prelude> mkPerson "" 12
Lefty [InvalidName,UnderAge]
Prelude> mkPerson "" 13
Lefty [InvalidName]
Prelude> mkPerson "Gerd" 13
Righty (Person {name = "Gerd", age = 13})
```

What could I have done different to make the code better?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Functor` instance doesn't need `a` to be a `Monoid`. We can remove that constraint to make `fmap` on `EitherLeftMonoid` more general.

Your `Applicative` instance could be made a little bit more readable if you provide a `fromLefty :: Monoid a => EitherLeftMonoid a b -> a` function:

```
instance Functor (EitherLeftMonoid a) where
  fmap _ (Lefty a)  = Lefty a
  fmap f (Righty b) = Righty (f b)

instance Monoid a => Applicative (EitherLeftMonoid a) where
  pure                  = Righty
  Righty f <*> Righty x = Righty (f x)
  x        <*> y        = Lefty $ fromLefty x `mappend` fromLefty y

fromLefty :: Monoid a => EitherLeftMonoid a b -> a
fromLefty (Left x) = x
fromLefty _        = mempty
```

With `fromLefty` we can take advantage of `mappend mempty x = x = mappend x mempty`.

---

In this case everything is in a single module and everything gets exported. This enables a user to use the `Person` constructor immediately. If you want to prevent that you need to make sure that only the type, but neither the records nor the data constructor get exported. Otherwise `mkPerson` can get circumvented.